# How can I find the execution time of a section of my program in C?

Tags: c, timing

I'm trying to find a way to get the execution time of a section of code in C. I've already tried both time() and clock() from time.h, but it seems that time() returns seconds and clock() seems to give me milliseconds (or centiseconds?)  I would like something more precise though. Is there a way I can grab the time with at least microsecond precision?

This only needs to be able to compile on Linux.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You referred to `clock()` and `time()` - were you looking for `gettimeofday()`?
That will fill in a `struct timeval`, which contains seconds and microseconds.

Of course the actual resolution is up to the hardware.

Answer (score 12):

For what it's worth, here's one that's just a few macros:

```
#include <time.h>
clock_t startm, stopm;
#define START if ( (startm = clock()) == -1) {printf("Error calling clock");exit(1);}
#define STOP if ( (stopm = clock()) == -1) {printf("Error calling clock");exit(1);}
#define PRINTTIME printf( "%6.3f seconds used by the processor.", ((double)stopm-startm)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Then just use it with:

```
main() {
  START;
  // Do stuff you want to time
  STOP;
  PRINTTIME;
}
```

From http://ctips.pbwiki.com/Timer

Answer (score 11):

You want a [profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiler_(computer_science)) application.

Search keywords at SO and search engines: linux profiling

Comment: A Profiler gives statistical information, which isn't the same as an actual measurement.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [gettimeofday](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gettimeofday.html),
[clock_*](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/clock_getres.html), or [get/setitimer](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getitimer.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try ["bench.h"](http://pastebin.com/f38ba0fa9); it lets you put a START_TIMER; and STOP_TIMER("name"); into your code, allowing you to arbitrarily benchmark any section of code (note: only recommended for short sections, not things taking dozens of milliseconds or more).  Its accurate to the clock cycle, though in some rare cases it can change how the code in between is compiled, in which case you're better off with a profiler (though profilers are generally more effort to use for specific sections of code).

It only works on x86.

Comment: Nice one, we have a similar one, with useful addition, PERF_MARK. This will allow to mark multiply point stored in static array. We have a version that can save a string to easy reading the results, array holds 100 entries by default but can be changed. PERF_STOP dump the results.

Comment: To whoever added the note about this failing on multi-core systems: I deleted it, because it is simply incorrect.  The macro automatically handles context switches and other sudden changes in RDTSC values, so no such problem exists.  I use it exclusively on multi-core machines and it works fine.

Comment: Dark Shikari: This cannot be correct, This macro cannot handle things like pre-emptive context switches. It simply cant. It will produce results, but they will not be accurate. Also the time it returns is calibrated to a Core2 processor (due to #define NOP_CYCLES) & would need to be changed to suit.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to google for an *instrumentation* tool.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find a library call which lets you get past the clock resolution of your platform.  Either use a profiler (man gprof) as another poster suggested, or - quick & dirty - put a loop around the offending section of code to execute it many times, and use clock().

Answer (score 1):

`gettimeofday()` provides you with a resolution of microseconds, whereas [`clock_gettime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) provides you with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp);
```

The `clk_id` identifies the clock to be used. Use `CLOCK_REALTIME` if you want a system-wide clock visible to all processes. Use `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` for per-process timer and `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` for a thread-specific timer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing on x86 or x64 why not use the Time Stamp Counter: [RDTSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDTSC).

It will be more reliable then Ansi C functions like time() or clock() as RDTSC is an atomic function. Using C functions for this purpose can introduce problems as you have no guarantee that the thread they are executing in will not be switched out and as a result the value they return will not be an accurate description of the actual execution time you are trying to measure.

With RDTSC you can better measure this. You will need to convert the tick count back into a human readable time H:M:S format which will depend on the processors clock frequency but google around and I am sure you will find examples.

However even with RDTSC you will be including the time your code was switched out of execution, while a better solution than using time()/clock() if you need an exact measurement you will have to turn to a profiler that will instrument your code and take into account when your code is not actually executing due to context switches or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the conditions.. Profilers are nice for general global views however if you really need an accurate view my recommendation is KISS.  Simply run the code in a loop such that it takes a minute or so to complete.  Then compute a simple average based on the total run time and iterations executed.

This approach allows you to:

1. Obtain accurate results with low resolution timers.
2. Not run into issues where instrumentation interferes with high speed caches (l2,l1,branch..etc) close to the processor.  However running the same code in a tight loop can also provide optimistic results that may not reflect real world conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which enviroment/OS you are working on, but your timing may be inaccurate if another thread, task, or process preempts your timed code in the middle. I suggest exploring mechanisms such as mutexes or semaphores to prevent other threads from preemting your process.