# How can I get the current time in milliseconds using C?

Tags: c, datetime

How might I get the current time in milliseconds in C? I am doing following to get the time in seconds:

```
struct tm ptm;

now = time(NULL);

localtime_r(&now,ptm);

myTime= (ptm->tm_hour * 3600) + (ptm->tm_min * 60) + (ptm->tm_sec);
```

Looking at time.h, `struct tm` does not have the millisecond member in it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361363/how-to-measure-time-in-milliseconds-using-ansi-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173409/how-can-i-find-the-execution-time-of-a-section-of-my-program-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- On Unix, use gettimeofday() to get the answer in microseconds and scale to milliseconds.
- Or use POSIX clock_gettime() to get the answer in nanoseconds and scale to milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I use **ftime** for time tracking ([link text](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/ftime.html))