# Measure execution time in C (on Windows)

Tags: c, windows, execution-time

Is there a better function or way to measure time than `clock()` function on Windows? I have a short operation and when I try `clock()` or `gettickcount()` it says it took 0.0 seconds. I need a way to measure it by miliseconds or nanoseconds.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
    LARGE_INTEGER start;
    LARGE_INTEGER end;
    double interval;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

    // code to be measured

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
    interval = (double) (end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / frequency.QuadPart;

    printf("%f\n", interval);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked with sequential search code. But it gives program stopped running error when i use it with a "Binary Search" code. What could be the problem?

Comment: Above code is tested, if you have problem, it's somewhere else. Debug your "Binary Search"... or, [ask your problem as a new StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: `interval` should be in seconds (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1739265) and [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`'s documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms644905.aspx))

Comment: Note that frequency could be 0 if the hardware doesn't support it. So it's probably best to add a check that it isn't 0,

Comment: In MSVC I understand that `clock()` gives wall time not execution time. I tried this QPC method in the hope of getting consistent timings (for profiling), but sadly the measured time varies here too. This is for periods of 1 second or more, and for operations that are exactly the same on each run, so it can't be measuring execution time. So I still have to make several runs and record the shortest time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) combined with [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get nanosecond precision.